# Hardware: Matching a CPU

Tags: cpu

So I've got an old machine I want to turn into a basic server (FTP, security camera, maybe a printer). It has [this processor](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/K7/AMD-Duron%20800%20-%20D800AUT1B.html). I want to put in the A1400AMS3C (Google it, serverfault won't let me post 2 hyperlinks) which is supposedly the fastest with the same socket.

How do I find out if it'll work? What besides socket needs to match? (I have basic hardware competency and can replace most components, but I've never changed CPUs and I don't want to waste my money).

I realize this is more hardware than systems administration; if there's a better place for this question, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to find the manual for the motherboard (might find it via Google) and see what the fastest processor it supports is. Without knowing that, it's impossible to know.

My knee-jerk guess is no, that Duron runs at 100MHz 8x; and the Athlon runs at 133MHz 10.5x; the different FSB speeds usually means different memory, and relatively few boards that came with 100MHz processors support 133MHz processors.

Side note: I wouldn't waste $30+ on an ancient machine upgrade like that. For $100 you can get a new MB & Processor that are 10+ times faster...

Comment: OK. Out of curiosity, what MB and CPU can I get for $100? When I've put together configurations on Newegg it's usually more like $100 each.

I can't ID the motherboard. It was a custom build many years ago, and there's no product number (as far as I can tell) on the board.

Comment: MB & CPU for $65: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813138195 RAM for $23: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820161400 This rig would be about 4x faster than the Athlon 1300. You might just run with the machine you've got now and upgrade when it's not keeping up anymore.